# How to validate Nested Conditional Validation in Yup Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

To condtionally validate a field, is

```
      addShippingAddress: Yup.boolean(),
      name: Yup.string().when('addShippingAddress', {
        is: true,
        then: (schema) => schema.required('Field is required'),
      }),
```

However, this doesn't work if the properly is 1 level above the current object.

```
  shipping: Yup.object().shape({
    addShippingAddress: Yup.boolean(),
    address: Yup.object().shape({
      name: Yup.string().when('addShippingAddress', {
        // Always says addShippingAddress is undefined, now will always set this as required, even though the addShippingAddress !== true
        is: true,
        then: (schema) => schema.required('Field is required'),
        otherwise: (schema) => schema,
      }),
```

Is there anyway to conditionally add a required validation for a nested object in Yup/Formik?

#### Versions:

```
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit: Found a way

This would use the address schema whenever the addShippingAddress is checked, otherwise there's no validation schema.
Only works because fields show when that checkbox is set.

However, not defining the initial fields leads to other complications.

**DO NOT initialise the address variables in initial values, otherwise it won't work**

```
const addressSchema = () => {
  return Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .max(300, 'Name is too long')
      .required('Name is required'),
  });
};

  shipping: Yup.object().shape({
    addShippingAddress: Yup.boolean(),
    address: addressSchema(false).when('addShippingAddress', {
      is: true,
      then: (schema) => schema, // Returns addressSchema with required 
      otherwise: (schema) => schema.default(undefined), 
    }),
```

#### Old Answer

Don't think it's possible, needed to move the `addShippingAddress` variable into the same object as the nested conditional.

```
    address: Yup.object().shape({
      addShippingAddress: Yup.boolean(),
      name: Yup.string().when('addShippingAddress', {
        is: true,
        then: (schema) => schema.required('Field is required'),
      }),


  // Formik Init vals
  shipping: {
    address: {
      addShippingAddress: false,
      name: '',
      ...
    },
```